# How to pass a variable which contains a query, to another page?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to pass a variable which contains a query, to another php page.
I have variable as follows.

```
$search_type = $_POST['search_type'];
$search_brand = $_POST['search_brand'];

$result = "SELECT * FROM vehicle_info WHERE type='".$search_type."' AND brand='".$search_brand;
```

Then I create a link to a different page, I want to pass the **$result** variable to that page.

```
<?php echo "<a href='$secondpage.php?data=$result'>Click Here</a>"; ?>
```

But when I click this link, the whole data doesn't carry out with the URL. When I click the link, my URL was like following

```
.../secondpage.php?data=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20vehicle_info%20WHERE%20type=
```

The URL doesn't contain the variables ($search_type and $search_brand)
So how can I make this possible? Please help me !

Comment: You're not querying `mysql` yet, so `$result` only contains your raw SQL statement. :)

Comment: regardless... sql injection alert!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: i would guess that $search_type and $search_brand are null, thus not returning any text to your URL

Comment: no they are not null. I checked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $_SESSION to store the query or you can encode the string using json-encode function and pass it in link

Answer (score 0):

```
$search_type = $_POST['search_type'];
$search_brand = $_POST['search_brand'];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vehicle_info WHERE type='".$search_type."' AND brand='".$search_brand) or die(mysql_error());  

while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
    extract($row);
    echo "<a href='secondpage.php?searchtype=$type&searchbrand=$brand'>Click Here</a>";
}
```

All of that is assuming your secondpage.php takes in the values searchtype and searchbrand to display the results. The problem was, you did not fetch the results, what you were displaying was the query itself.